# Image Caching in Android

Tags: android, image, caching, android-glide

I'm looking for the best practice solution to Cache images in android .. I considered Glide in my code implementation like below:

```
   RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .signature(new ObjectKey(logo));

        Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(logo).apply(requestOptions).into(view);
```

but it doesn't load cached images when app is offline, So what is the best way to handle Image caching?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Glide like this:

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                .dontAnimate()
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //Use a placeholder image
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                .priority(Priority.HIGH);


        Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load(uri)
                .thumbnail(0.1f)
                .apply(options)
                .into(view);
```

Comment: I'll try it, Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the Picasso instead:

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .into(image_view)
```

Because Picasso automatically caches the loaded images, so, the next time they will be loaded from the cache. You can check whether the image is loaded from the web, cache or disk by enabling the indicator

```
setIndicatorsEnabled(true)
```

Comment: I'll try it, Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but you can check out the **ColdStorage library** (https://github.com/crypticminds/ColdStorage) for caching images with just annotations.

Simply annotate the image view with the annotation

```
@LoadImage(R.id.my_image_view, "url_to_download_image_from")
ImageView imageview;
```

and it will take care of downloading the image, loading it into the image view and putting it in the cache.
You can also show a placeholder image and loading animation using the annotation.

A detailed description of the annotation is present here:-
https://github.com/crypticminds/ColdStorage/wiki/@LoadImage-annotation